# AWS elasticbeanstak EbExtensionPostBuild and EbExtensionPreBuild executioners

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Good day,

I am in the process of deploying some of my applications to elasticbeanstalk on AWS, now from reading the documentation and tutorials i get it all deployed and working, but there is a big thing missing in the AWS documentation that i need to know. i can not find the information i am seeking for anywhere, can someone please give me a link to the documentation explaining this or just explain it to me please.

Who and what and from where does is the EbExtensionPreBuild and EbExtensionPostBuild actions executed, who calls them, what do they run and where do they get the commands from?

There are in total 6 actions being performed and nowhere on the internet does AWS explain what happends in these actions.

InfraWriteConfig...
DownloadSourceBundle...
EbExtensionPreBuild...
AppDeployPreHook...
EbExtensionPostBuild...
InfraCleanEbextension...

can someone please explain these actions and link them to the bits of code they execute from the .ebextensions folder .config files.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The environment that used to answer you question is a **PHP 7.3 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.2**, but, maybe to others platforms, like docker the answer is the same, or at least in how to find the answer.

You can find in log file **/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log** the log of all tasks that was executed in your server, the most common task is the deployment task **CMD-AppDeploy**.

This task is responsible to execute the following scripts:

**CMD-AppDeploy**

First stage : **AppDeployStage0**

**DownloadSourceBundle**:
- /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/download-source-bundle

**EbExtensionPreBuild**
- /opt/elasticbeanstalk/eb_infra/infra-embedded_prebuild.rb

**AppDeployPreHook**
- /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre

**EbExtensionPostBuild**
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/eb_infra/infra-embedded_postbuild.rb

**InfraCleanEbextension**
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/eb_infra/infra-clean_ebextensions_dir.rb

Second stage : **AppDeployStage1**

**AppDeployEnactHook**
- /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact

**AppDeployPostHook**
- /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post

You have more than one task available in Beanstalk, you can find the full config in file: **/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/configuration/containerconfiguration**

Each script is a small part in the deployment process, if you need more details in how the deployment is done, I suggest you check each script individually.